# how to disable default infoWindow in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a google map applications, i am loading polygons from another kml file which stored in database. That kml file contains polygon and default infoWindow (when click inside the polygon ), i want to disable that infowindow. please tell me how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: post some code  you tried it would be easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Google Maps API v3 KmlLayer to display the KML, the default InfoWindow can be disabled with the [suppressInfoWindows:true](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) property in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Still i have the problem that when i am click on the map, the hand symbol appear and does nothing. I am try with the {clickable:false} but not working. how to remove that hand symbol when mouse event invoke.

Comment: That is a different question and possibly an issue with the version of the API you are using (which you haven't told us), sounds like this answer worked for your original question.